# Add color to nose2 output

Tags: python, nose2

This is such a simple question, but I can't find it anywhere... how do I add color to the output of running tests with nose2? For example, I would like failures to show up as red.

Answer (score 3):

`nose2` does not have colored output built in, but a popular third-party plugin named **green** will color the output for you.

It can easily be installed with pip via : `pip3 install green`

You can find more information on it within it's pypi page here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/green

Their GitHub page as well: https://github.com/CleanCut/green

Comment: `green` is not a nose2 plugin, it's a completely different program which does not support the same things nose(2) does.